# How to remove parent element on click? - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, parent

I have a button beside my list item which is to remove the list item.

My button is inside the list so I am trying to find a way to remove the parent element.  I have a directive able to remove the element itself but not with the parent. I tried adding `parent.remove()` instead of just `remove()` but I kept on getting error with AngularJS doesn't know what parent is.

I have my **html** as

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{ pos: 'column1' }">
   <li>{{item.name}}<button remove-on-click ng-click="remove()" 
       class="remove-button fa fa-times"></button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I have my **directive** as

```
.directive('removeOnClick', function() {
  return {
     link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
       scope.remove = function () {
           element.remove();
       };
     }
   }
 });
```

Can someone please give me a hand?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you want to remove the ul or the li?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement

Comment: @guradio I want to remove the li

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/hfao8obe/

Comment: @guradio the fiddle didn't work also I want it using angularJS instead of jQuery though

Answer (score 3):

omg! I am so sorry everyone, I kept on trying `parent` and other ways and now I found out my stupidest mistake!  Just using `parent().remove()` would eventually work!

Answer (score 0):

Write **$event** inside your **ng-click="remove()"** function ,so the ng-click function will be **ng-click="remove($event);"**

```
$scope.remove = function(e){
    console.log(e.target); // you can see button in console
    $(e.target).parent().remove();
}
```